# ASP.NET MVC 3 jQuery Unobtrusive Valdiation - Field Error Reset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I noticed in one of the forms I am working on, for example a Textbox of type "number" and another of type "jquery UI datepicker", when form is submitted and no values in those fields, a red border appears putting those two fields in error state.

I change the values and remove focus from those fields, the fields are still showing red border, however, when i submit again, it works.

Other fields behave as follows, in case a field is in error state, I add some data, step out of the field, the red border is removed.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Your description is fine but it would be absolutely great if you could post a narrowed down and yet full code allowing to exemplify this description.

Comment: This is part of an application that i can't post here. What piece code might give you a hint to post? Thanks

Comment: I am not asking you to post your actual application code. I am asking you to post a narrowed down version that will allow people to reproduce the problem you are talking about. As far as which part you need to post is concerned, well in order for us to reproduce, we will obviously need a sample model, controller, view and javascript part. Otherwise you realize that we cannot get compile and get a working version that illustrates your problem.